# static top navigation with the content hiding behind it on scroll

Tags: html, css

Here is a fiddle as to what I am trying to accomplish: http://jsfiddle.net/60h84j7u/

I want the copy to hide below the top-nav div. I can accomplish this if the background is set to something other than transparent but in this case, the background for top-nav needs to be transparent.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="top-nav">This needs to be at top</div>

    <div class="copy"><p>This needs to hide below the top-nav as the user scrolls thru the page.</p></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    /*border: 1px solid purple;*/
}
.top-nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    border: 1px solid red;
    background: transparent;
}

.copy {
    position: relative;
    top: 40px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: why does the background need to be transparent?

Comment: If your background is transparent, it means you want the text underneath to show.

Comment: no, he wants the background to be transparent but have the text stop showing at the bottom border of it. I just want to know why he needs it to be transparent as their are other ways to do what I think he's trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this to be impossible if you want the scrollbar to be on the edge of the browser, unless you change your design decision to make the top-nav transparent and do something else, such as adding a background colour or background image that shows the same thing.

If you add 2 fixed containers* around the scrollable part of your page, set their height to something < 100% and position them under your top-nav, you can set the outer container to hide overflow, and set the inner container to scroll on the y-axis. This does not really yield great results.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="top-nav">This needs to be at top</div>

    <div id="outercontainer">
        <div id="innercontainer">
            <div class="copy"><p>This needs to hide below the top-nav as the user scrolls thru the page.</p></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

with css:

```
.outercontainer {
    position: fixed;
    top: 40px;
    height: 90%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.innercontainer {
    position: fixed;
    height: 90%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

* tested in Internet Explorer 11. Might horribly break in anything else